# how to parse local xml file in android using dom and saxparser?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, android-parser

how to parse local xml file in android using dom and sax?

Comment: Android simply provide a SAX parser for parsing. Go thru it on android developer site

Comment: @Shaireen what about DOM, doesn't Android provide DOM parsing?

Comment: It does.. but SAX parser is used most of the times.For DOM chk http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser.. Apart from all dis XMLPULL Parser is also provided

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a simple SAXParser for developers: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

So use the `SAXParserFactory` to create a parser. Then use the sub class of `DefaultHandler` to handle all parse events.

One more relevant class is the `PullParser`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html